# Does Viagra become less effective at tackling Erectile Dysfunction with repeated use?

Tags: medical-science, sexuality, erectile-dysfunction

This 2003 article, [*Long-term Tolerance With Viagra*](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/460334) suggests that there is a consensus amongst authorities that sildenafil (Viagra) does not have a [tachyphylactic effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyphylaxis) - i.e. it doesn't diminish in its effectiveness after repeated use:

> The results of the El-Galley study were largely discounted upon poor
>   follow-up; 50% of the men on sildenafil did not respond to a telephone
>   interview at 2 years' follow-up. In contrast, a 3-year follow-up study
>   in nerve-sparing radical prostatectomy patients (n = 41) revealed that
>   71% (29/41) were still responding to the same dose of sildenafil.[4]
>   Of the 29% of dropouts, half (6/12) stopped because of return of
>   spontaneous erections, with only 5 of 12 gradually losing efficacy.
>   Hence, **most authorities have attributed loss of sildenafil efficacy
>   not to tachyphylaxis**, but to progression in organic disease from
>   associated comorbidities and aging.
>
> However, a recent study using cultured rat cavernosal smooth muscle
>   cells demonstrated molecular upregulation of the phosphodiesterase
>   type 5 (PDE-5) enzyme when the cells treated with high doses of
>   sildenafil for at least 7 days.[5] These findings suggest that
>   sildenafil is safe and effective when used at normal clinical doses
>   and recommended dosing frequencies. However, additional clinical
>   research will be needed to evaluate the tachyphylaxis effect in
>   chronic PDE-5 inhibitor use, especially when these agents possess long
>   half-lives.

Is the article conclusive? Are there any other studies that backup this claims? Twelve years have passed - is this still the consensus of medical world now?

Comment: There have been a couple more studies [that are quoted here](http://www.livestrong.com/article/75866-longterm-effects-using-viagra/), and one of them stating that repeated use creates a psychological dependency on the drug. But none of these mention something similar to your quote.

Comment: @Abel, would you like to expand your answer?